# calling a static variable inside php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the array value by using php static variable like this

```
$a = $_GET['type'];

if($a==1)
{
 $variable  = 'cost';
 $tablename = 'logistics_bluedart';
}
else if($a==2)
{
  $variable = 'shp_cost';
  $tablename = 'logistics_prof';
}
else if($a==3)
{
  $variable ='shipping_cost';
  $tablename = 'logistics_firstflight';
}

$myQuery = mysql_query("select $variable from $tablename");

while($resultData = mysql_fetch_array($myQuery)){

echo $resultData[$variable];

}
```

But I am not getting any output?

Comment: static variable? You keep using that word, but maybe [it doesn't mean what you think it means](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) . Possible problems: `$a` is not what you think; `$type` is not defined in your code

Comment: Can you provide logistics table structure here.

Comment: okay, so where is the information that people might need to help you figure out why? echo your query, what does it say? echo a, what does it say? What's your table data? etc.

Comment: I don't see any `static` keyword anywhere.

Comment: `$type` doesn't seem defined. It is likely that your query fails.

Comment: 1) You should learn PDO instead of mysql_query.  2) To debug, echo each step along the way to see where it's breaking.

Comment: are u sure that must be     $type in the sql query, and not just "type"?

Comment: it should work fine. What error do you get?

Comment: @kamal0808  I am just getting a blank output

Comment: Then there has to be a problem with your SQL structure, because the php code is just fine. Can u provide the SQL structure for tables? And also ensure that $_GET['type'] has a valid value

Answer (score 0):

Please Check into while loop

```
print_r($resultData);
```

it's return array you have kay like cost,shp_cost,shipping_cost that key have in to array.

```
Other wise used mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery) instend of mysql_fetch_array($myQuery).
```

Answer (score 0):

**change this line:**

```
$myQuery = mysql_query("select $variable from logistics where $type = $a");
```

**Replace:**

```
$myQuery = mysql_query("select $variable from logistics where type = $a");//replace $type to type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
check the $_GET['type'] must not empty.
then check $a must have the values in 1,2,3.
```

If any of the above is not following then you will not get results according to code you mention above.

-

Thanks